# Gcc/G++ doesn't give correct results when compiling more than 3 times

Tags: c, gcc

I created a program in C for a class in my college (on Linux with gcc) that do some calculus. The program works fine the first and second time i compiled it and run it (gcc name of file -o name of output file), but the third time always gives different values without having changed any code. My question is...the problem is in gcc/g++ or in my code? On Windows under Dev-C++ it works fine no matter how many times i run it. Apologies about the indentation if it is wrong/weird i had some trouble indenting here on the site and didn't have time to pay much attention to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float bullinton(float *altobj, float *distobj, float transmissor, float receptor, int n){

int i=0,j,l,w, k=0, count_tgt=0, count_tgr=0, max_tgt=0, max_tgr=0, max=0;
float tgt[n], tgr[n], somatorio_dist=0, alt=0, maxtgt=0, maxtgr=0, soma_transmissor, soma_recetor;  //tangentes do transmissor e receptor

    //Linha de vista para o transmissor
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        soma_transmissor+=distobj[i];
        tgt[i]=(altobj[i]-transmissor)/(soma_transmissor);
    }

    //Linha de vista para o receptor
    for(i=n-1,k=n;i>=0;i--){
        soma_recetor+=distobj[i+1];
        tgr[i]=(altobj[i]-receptor)/(soma_recetor);
    }

    //Mostra os valores da tangente e do receptor em cada posição
    for(i=0,k=n;i<=n && k!=0;i++,k--){
        printf("A tangente do transmissor na %d posição e: %.2f\nA tangente do receptor na %d e: %.2f\n",i,tgt[i],k,tgr[i]);    
    }

    //valor maximo de tgt
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(tgt[i]>tgt[max_tgt]){
            max_tgt=i;
        }
    }   

    //valor maximo de tgr
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(tgr[i]>tgr[max_tgr]){
            max_tgr=i;
        }

    }

    //Mostra o valor maximo de tgt e tgr
    printf("O valor maximo de tgt e: %.2f\nO valor maximo de tgr e: %.2f\n",tgt[max_tgt],tgr[max_tgr]);

    if(transmissor==receptor){
        for(i=0;i<n+1;i++){
            somatorio_dist+=distobj[i];
        }
    }

    float tgtt=1/tgt[max_tgt];
    float tgrr=1/tgr[max_tgr];

    alt=somatorio_dist/(tgtt + tgrr);   

    printf("Tgtt=%.2f\nTgrr=%.2f\n",tgtt,tgrr);
    printf("Somatorio %.2f\nA altura e: %.2f\n", somatorio_dist,alt);
}

int main(){

    int i, numero_objectos=0;
    float altura_objecto[numero_objectos], distancia_objecto[numero_objectos], transmissor, receptor;


    puts("Introduza o numero de objectos: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero_objectos);

    for(i=0;i<numero_objectos;i++){
        printf("Introduza a altura para o %d objecto:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&altura_objecto[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<numero_objectos+1;i++){
        printf("Introduza a distancia para o %d objecto:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&distancia_objecto[i]);
    }

    puts("Introduza a altura do transmissor: ");
    scanf("%f",&transmissor);

    puts("Introduza a altura do receptor: ");
    scanf("%f",&receptor);

    bullinton(altura_objecto, distancia_objecto, transmissor, receptor, numero_objectos);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest after every two compilations to buy a new computer!

Comment: Why the C++ tags ? This is apparently C code for a C programming class ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example when asking questions like this, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out. Thanks @TartanLlama for the last comment it makes total sense. So the "core error" (the thing that i wanted to know) was in here:

```
float /*  */ soma_transmissor, soma_recetor;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   soma_transmissor+=distobj[i];
   /*  */
}

for(i=n-1,k=n;i>=0;i--){
   soma_recetor+=distobj[i+1];
   /*  */
}
```

I just needed to inicialize soma_transmissor and soma_recetor. Now if anyone knows why i had to do this to ensure that the correct results appears all the time (when using gcc and not with DevC++) please do share, because I'm completely clueless of the reason. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 5):

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour.

```
int i, numero_objectos=0;
float altura_objecto[numero_objectos], distancia_objecto[numero_objectos], transmissor, receptor;
```

Here you declare `altura_objecto` and `distancia_objecto` as zero-length arrays. No matter what you do to `numero_objectos` later on, those arrays will still be invalid. You could maybe put those declarations after you read the number of objects, but variable length arrays are a compiler extension; they aren't standard.

You would be better off declaring those arrays as `std::vector<float>` instead. That is assuming that you are actually using C++. You shouldn't tag your questions as both C and C++, they are very different languages at this point.

Comment: Despite the C++ tags this appears to be C code for a C programming class, so the VLAs are OK, so long as the OP fixes the dimension (`numero_objectos`).

Comment: OP also says he uses the Dev-C++ compiler. IDK.

Comment: Still, probably used as C compiler no?

Comment: @TartanLlama Yeah, sorry for the C++ tag i was in a hurry, this code is writen in C only...i already deleted the flag. I defined a "MAX" variable for the arrays with 20 elements/posicions. The error persists...i compile and run it and the values are all right...but when i compile and run it a second time (without touching the code) the values are all different and wrong. This happens on Linux with gcc...on Windows with DevC++ everything is fine.

Comment: Why define an arbitrary size when you are about to read in the actual size? Just declare the arrays when you actually know the size.

Answer (score 1):

you're creating an array of size zero, since numero_objectos gets 0 assigned and the arrays are created with that number. Arrays can't be dynamically scaled like that.

What you want is something dynamic array. For that you first ask for the array size as you do now and then do a memory allocation with that number.
Like this:

```
float *altura_objecto, *distancia_objecto;
puts("Introduza o numero de objectos: ");
scanf("%d",&numero_objectos);
altura_objecto = malloc(numero_objectos * sizeof(*altura_objecto));
distancia_objecto = malloc(numero_objectos * sizeof(*distancia_objecto));
```

that will create the arrays of the desired sizes. You have to free that memory after you're done though. You do this by calling free() with the respective pointers as parameter.

Comment: C99 and later has VLAs, so no need for malloc unless `numero_objectos` is likely to be large.

Comment: yeah, but you don't know what the user will type, so better safe than sorry. And if you're referring to my line about scaling the array it was more about the fact that the size in this code is determined after the declaration of the arrays and that a change to the size variable won't affect the arrays.